# Can't import android.support.v7.appcompact

Tags: android

[image]

I imported android.support-v7.appcompact.jar and android.support-v4.jar( I added it in the library and I configured the file path) but I still have this error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create a library project for the v7 support library?

Comment: you need to import the v7 project from `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/`

Comment: I edited my post so you can see how I added v4 and v7 support

Comment: @Marya you need to import the project in order to use resources.

Comment: read this doc https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: I already made the setup @SpringBreaker as mentionned in the link

Comment: @AtifFarrukh what do you mean by import the project ?? 
I imported jars and configured the file path

Comment: From you snapshot it looks like you added the jar files to `libs` folder where as you need to import the support project to eclipse and add it as a library to your project.

Comment: @SpringBreaker i did all what you said but the error remains !!